# adding PATH in /etc/profile and ~/.bash_profile but not showing via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, bash

on Centos 6.x,

I am adding some path `export PATH=$PATH:/some/path`

in both `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile`

but if it's not effective when I login via SSH

it only shows if I type `source .bash_profile`

What am I doing wrong?

(N.B. for logging via SSH I use the following alias: `alias ssh-server='ssh -t user@server "cd /some/dir/ ; bash"`)

Comment: Since neither `/etc/profile` nor `~/.bash_profile` is being read, it looks like you are using an *interactive non-login shell*. Only login shells read those files. However an interactive SSH session starts a login shell. Is your `~/.bashrc` being processed?

Comment: I just tested that if I add `export PATH=$PATH:/some/path` to `~/.bashrc`, it actually gets added, but twice! what's going on?

Comment: This confirms that you are runnnig an interactive *non-login* shell instead of a login shell. Are you logging in to the system and executing commands or are you providing a command as argument to `ssh`?

Comment: I use ssh via this alias, which I copied from somewhere:
`alias ssh-server='ssh -t user@server "cd /some/dir/ ; bash"'`. I am now wondering what's the meaning of that `bash` at the end, and whether is affecting something

Comment: Why are you using that alias? If you want to change the directory, create an entry in `.profile` or `.bashrc`. If you want to change your shell, use `chsh`. If you want to save some typing, create a shorthand in `.ssh/config`.

Comment: Hi Marco, I am using that alias, because it's handy: I can edit the whole command in just one line. By the way, I found the solution to my problem: I need to add `--login` after bash: `alias ssh-server='ssh -t user@server "cd /some/dir/ ; bash --login"`, which tells the bash that is a login shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile` are not read is that you
are not using an *interactive login shell*. A “normal” login, e.g. via

```
ssh myserver
```

creates an interactive login shell, in contrast to executing
commands provided as argument to `ssh`, which use a non-login shell.
An interactive non-login bash reads the files `/etc/bash.bashrc` and
`~/.bashrc`.

If you want to change the directory for interactive login shells,
add your `cd /some/dir` to one of the following files. The first one
found, is being processed, the others are ignored.

```
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile
```

If your user name or host name is too long to type, create an alias
in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host server
HostName me.and.my.server.somedomain.tld
User daniele
```

Comment: thanks a lot Marco for the clear explanation! By the way, I found the way to execute commands as an argument of ssh and still have an interactive login shell, just by adding the `--login` parameter to the bash:
`ssh -t user@server "cd /some/dir/ ; bash --login"`